# Monitor Coldfusion on linux with monit?

Tags: coldfusion, jrun, monit

We are trying to use monit to monitor services on our Ubuntu machine. I have successfully setup a host url check to make sure that coldfusion can render web pages and it there is an error to restart coldfusion.

I was wondering if there is a way to get more stats into monit by monitoring the coldfusion process. I have been unable to find out if coldfusion creates a pid file.

Does Coldfusion 9 or Jrun create a pid file for monit to use? Is there another way to monitor coldfusion with monit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create the PID file with a wrapper script around your Java application. I'm doing the same thing myself these days. To the best of my understanding monit has to have the PID file to check the life of your service.

Answer (score 1):

ColdFusion can output real-time performance metrics such as:

- Page hits per second
- Database accesses per second
- Number of queued requests
- Number of running requests
- Number of timed out requests
- Average queue time
- Average request time
- Average database transaction time
- Bytes incoming per second
- Bytes outgoing per second

You can learn more about the output of this logging here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7fe0.html#WS9F365555-357A-4a15-AC72-449EF611E342

I would be interested to learn how you set this up once complete. I'll have the same task in a few weeks.

Thanks!

Comment: I also found a path in a help note from a few years ago:cat /opt/coldfusion/log/pids/server.pid

Comment: No luck on the pid file. Monit provides functionality to view what is happening with the process on linux, like cpu and memory usage and to execute actions when things get out of control, like restarting the service or sending out at alert.

Comment: Have you tried searching *.pid under your ColdFusion dir when the app is running?

Comment: I have to no avail. It seems that java applications do not natively run with a pid file.

Comment: Perhaps this post may help: http://blog.igorminar.com/2007/03/how-java-application-can-discover-its.html